# Avoiding loss of session variables when web.config and bin folder changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

We have a ASP.net website and I use session variables. But when customer was using my website, If i change  the web.config then it causes application pool to restart and all sessions gets lost.

Now in my case the website is for submitting query from customers. So the data from customer will be written to our database once he submits the page or form. Now all the information like customer number ,name etc will be lost and only his query(which is not a session variable) will be submitted. So we get only query and no information related who has posted it. So it becomes a serious problem for us to find who has posted it.

Also if I change the bin folder files then does it cause the same problem?
So what are the best solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is expected behavior for in-memory session state - restarts of IIS or recycle of application pool or recycle of app domain will kill the state. I.e. changing `web.config` or touching enough files in the site (including bin folder) will lead to app-domain recycle by built in ASP.Net logic.

To solve it use out-of-process ASP.Net SQL session state: build in SQL session state or state service, there are also many other implementation of session state for ASP.Net.

Comment: Does SQL session state is easy to implement? And does it solve all the problems? Any disadvantages of using this method?

Comment: Out-of-process session storage will 1) disable the Session_OnEnd event and 2) require that all stored values are serializable.

Comment: @ITresearcher "easy" is very subjective: one needs MS SQL database server which may require effort to setup/configure depending on environment (you seem to require one already - may not be big problem) and as Simon Svensson commented it likely will require serious effort to make sure all objects are serializable and don't have live references to each other. I'd not expect Session_OnEnd to be a problem as it is very strange event anyway since there is not much relation to actual user session and it is not guaranteed to be fired anyway on restart...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Does setting restartOnExternalChanges  to false will help? If i set this then does changes made by me in bin folder will effect the application?

Comment: @ITresearcher - I don't know.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I just tried using server state session and it worked. I have not made any changes in coding otherthan web.config. But i found that the object must be serializable. But i hav not done anything and it works. So is there anything i have to change for serializable objects?

Comment: @ITresearcher - You may be fine. All basic types (like `int`/`string`) and many existing types (like `List`) are serializable so if you only put such objects into `Session` you don't need to do anything. Sometime people store non-serializable objects (directly or as part of other class) like `SQLConnection` or controls and it will not work with out-of-process session state (likely already problem anyway due to mismatched lifetime of objects, but not easily noticeable with in-memory session state).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If i set cookieless="false" then is there any problem for IIS recycle and web.config changes etc?

Comment: @ITresearcher cookieless attribute only controls how sessionId is send to server, there is no impact on how data is stored in session state. Note that in general it is bad idea to put session id in the url (i.e. one can share url with session id inadvertently).