# Best approaches to set session timeout

Tags: asp.net, session, timeout, stateserver

We have created a ASP.NET website to give ticket-based support to our customers. The customer  can send queries to us, and they can see replies, if any(we do provide application on customer side to send quires and replies).I am using ASP.net state server sessions in our asp website. Application checks for new replies in database for a duration of 45 minutes.After 45 minutes those sessions are no longer used.If no replies are present then it  checks for replies on next day. If customer puts new question then we create new session for it, and old session is no longer used.  To check on next day we directly fetch it from our database and show all replies which are not seen. Before I had asked question about [loss of session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980967/avoiding-loss-of-session-variables-when-web-config-and-bin-folder-changes) and then I solved it by using asp.net StateServer.

Now I have set session time out to 1440 i.e 24 hours. But we need to check replies for 45 minutes so we can reduce session timeout I think.But to be on safer side we set it to 24 hours.

1. Is there any negative effect if I set it to large values?
2. Does it effect on my web server performance?
3. What is the best approach to set session time-out in my case.

Comment: Initially if you want to "schedule" something in your site you could use global asax and timers. Session lives in the sever and reserves server memory. It is not so good to have user's session reserve memory 24/7. That's my opinion.

Comment: @kostasch. Session timeout value is from the time it craeted or it from the time it last updated?

I mean If session timeout is 10 mins and session variable gets updated or used after 5 mins after it created,  then session will expire after 10 min from it updated?

Comment: Check this out http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp/session

Comment: @kostasch. "Specifies the maximum period of time (hh:mm:ss) that a session object is maintained after the last request associated with the object is made" - So last request with object means just accessing the session variable also?